# MUI-Datatable: Displaying the data shows this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

When I added `data` here inside the `MuiDatatable`, it will show this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

How do I fix this and display the data?

I have recreated the issue in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fog-s984v0?file=/src/App.js

Codes:

```
export default function App() {
  console.log(data);
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "id",
      label: "System ID", //or the order ID here
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        display: false
      }
    },

    {
      label: "Name",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Address",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true
      }
    },

    {
      label: "Cart Items",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Total Amount",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true
      }
    }
  ];
  const options = {
    filter: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    responsive: "simple"
    // onRowClick: handleRowClick,
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme()}>
        {" "}
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Reports"}
          options={options}
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your data defined? Please make sure that data is an array of objects with structure as your columns array of the table.

Comment: My data is in the `data.js`

Comment: I have looked into the sandbox you have provided and yes the conflict is with the columns array you are defining in the App Js and data Js. For example the name field of the column array should match the key in data which you want to display in that column. But in your case it is not the same. Please have a look into it. thanks

Comment: oh you were right, Thank you. Now, if I'll add the `CartItems`, this is what it shows, `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {color, size, quantity, id, cat, name, price})`